# OpenGL frustum culling with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, culling

I'm currently programming a voxel engine with LWJGL and I want to optimize the fps.
Can you explain me how to find out if a block is in the view of the camera? The informations I have are cubeX, cubeY, cubeZ, cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ, cameraPitch & cameraYaw.

Comment: You can't do frustum culling if you don't know the frustum. Camera position and orientation is far from being enough.

Comment: Ok. How can I get to know the frustum?

Comment: Was heißt eigentlich frustrum auf deutsch?

Comment: It is your code, we can't know how you set up your view frustum ("Pyramidenstumpf")

Comment: You will need to calculate the frustum, in addition to cmaera position and orientation you will also need the viewport dimensions you are rendering to and distance to near/far planes, this is an (old) but thorough tutorial: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/